# Firebug shows POST info, but I can't echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that seems to `POST` successfully after submitting via `AJAX`. Under "NET" in Firebug the posted info displays properly. But I cannot `echo` this data at all.

I'm trying this, which is the 1st field in my form: `<?php echo $_POST['sun_exposure']; ?>`

Does this have anything to do with the form's `ACTION` not having a url?

Also, I'm trying to `POST` data to the same page, and not a PHP file. Maybe this is part of the problem?  This is also a Wordpress page, and not a file.

Here's the live url: http://www.richmindonline.com/container-creations/personal-creations-assistant/

Here's the form code:

```
<form id="quotation_form" name="vdmQuotationForm" action="#" method="post">               
    <div id="page1">
        <div id="step0_header" class="steps-headers" onClick="step0ToggleClick();">Step 1<span style="margin-left:30px;">Sun Exposure</span></div>
        <div id="step0" class="quotation-steps"><strong>Describe the sun exposure of your planter...</strong><br/>
            <div class="radio-container"><input onchange="go_to_next_step();" type="radio" name="sun_exposure[]" id="full_sun" value="Full Sun"<?php checked( 'Full Sun',$_POST['sun_exposure[]']); ?> /><label class="label-quotation-steps">Full Sun</label><br class="clear"/></div>
            <div class="radio-container"><input onchange="go_to_next_step();" type="radio" name="sun_exposure[]" id="part_sun" value="Part Sun"<?php checked( 'Part Sun',$_POST['sun_exposure[]']); ?> /><label class="label-quotation-steps">Part Sun</label><br class="clear"/></div>
            <div class="radio-container"><input onchange="go_to_next_step();" type="radio" name="sun_exposure[]" id="full_shade" value="Full Shade"<?php checked( 'Full Shade',$_POST['sun_exposure[]']); ?> /><label class="label-quotation-steps">Full Shade</label><br class="clear"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here's the `AJAX` request, which is wrapped up in the jQuery validate script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#quotation_form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                'sun_exposure[]': {
                    required: true,
                },
                'height[]': {
                    required:true,
                },
                'diameter[]': {
                    required:true,
                },
                'shape[]': {
                    required:true,
                },
                'placement[]': {
                    required:true,
                },
            },
            messages: {
                'sun_exposure[]': {
                    required: 'Please choose a sun exposure for your plant',
                },
                'height[]': {
                    required: 'Please choose the height of your planter'
                },
                'diameter[]': {
                    required: 'Please choose the diamter of your planter'
                },
                'shape[]': {
                    required: 'Please choose the shape of your planter'
                },
                'placement[]': {
                    required: 'Please choose the placement of your planter' 
                },                        
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                alert(error.text());
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo    
                var form_data = $("#quotation_form").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.richmindonline.com/container-creations/personal-creations-assistant/",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

                $('#page1').hide();
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('body').offset().top }, 10);
                $('#page2').show(); 
                $('.intro').hide();
                $('.to_page1').show();

                return false;    
            }
        }); // end .validate() 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try to print print_r($_POST); then check is there any redirection in page .

Comment: hi @messi fan, it prints `Array()` and there is no re-direction. thanks

Comment: You said you are using `$_POST` to the same page. Do you mean on the same page as the ajax function? In that case it's no wonder your `$_POST` doesn't work.

Comment: @user007, yes that is correct, I'm posting data on same page as `AJAX` function.  So this is not going to work?

Comment: @RobMyrick Yes, I just tried something short. Using `var_dump($_POST);` on same page returns the whole page code (along with HTML). If you send to a different file through AJAX and `echo json_encode($_POST);` on that file, it returns the posted values.

Comment: @user007, so maybe I create a text file or PHP file right, and then post values there?  Or can I simply create a new wordpress page and post the values to that url?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't worked with Wordpress, I'll up this question hoping someone familiar with Wordpress platform can help you.

Comment: @RobMyrick No create a simple php file and post to that file, wordpress pages are bloated with header, footers and what not, if you dont make a template file which in the end take you back to option one, create a php file